# Finding Splitting Field with Minimal Adjoined Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

I have to find the splitting field of the following in $\mathbb{Q}$:

a) $f(x) = x^6 + 1 $

b) $f(x) = (x^2-3)(x^3+1) $

For a), finding the 6th roots of -1, I concluded that $\pm i, \frac{\pm \sqrt{3} \pm i}{2}$ should be in the splitting field. The minimum adjoined splitting field is thus $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3},i]$.

For b) using similar method, I found that $-1, \sqrt{3}, \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$ should be in the splitting field. Is the minimal adjoined field for b) $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3},i]$ as well?

I am not so sure in how to find the minimal elements one must adjoin to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What do you mean by minimal adjoined elements?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

Comment: Also note that $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ and similarly
$$x^6+1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1).$$
**Hint:** These factors are all cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: I need to find the splitting fields of those polynomials by adjoining elements to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "*the* minimal elements"? As hinted by the link above, the splitting field over $\Bbb Q$ can be generated by a single element, but such an element is far from unique.

Answer (score 1):

Both splitting fields are equal to
$\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt3)=\Bbb Q[i,\sqrt3]$,
as you correctly wrote.

You still didn't reply what you mean by "minimal adjoined elements", but if what you want is as few generators as possible, the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) tells you that one is sufficient. Anyway, you don't need that theorem: you can take for instance
$$\alpha:=i+\sqrt3.$$
Indeed,
$$i=\frac{\alpha^3}8\quad\text{and}\quad\sqrt3=\alpha-i.$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, note that $x^6+1$ divides $x^{12}-1$, and that all roots of $x^{12}-1$ are contained in $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{12})$, where $\zeta_{12}$ denotes a primitive $12$-th root of unity. Because
$$[\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{12}):\Bbb{Q}]=\varphi(12)=4,$$
we see that this is a quartic extension containing all roots of $x^6+1$. You have already shown that any splitting field of $x^6+1$ must contain $i$ and $\sqrt{3}$, from which it easily follows that the degree of a splitting field must be at least $4$. This shows that $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{12})$ is a splitting field of $x^6+1$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

For the second question, a similar argument works, with slightly more effort.

Comment: I see, so are the fields I described the splitting fields of the polynomials?

Comment: Yes. It is not clear to me what you mean by 'minimal adjoined elements' though. Each splitting field can be generated by adjoining a single element to $\Bbb{Q}$, maybe that is what you're after? That is what I tried to do here.

Comment: Yes, I need to adjoin the fewest possible elements to $\mathbb{Q}$. Here, I have adjoined two elements in a) and in b). What would the single element to adjoin be then?

Comment: By the primitive element theorem, every finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ is generated by a single element. I've already given you a single element for the first question.

Comment: I see, I am in an introductory course of Abstract Algebra and we have yet to see the primitive element theorem. So far, we have been adjoining multiple element to $\mathbb{Q}$ to generate the splitting field.